# How does conversion operator return a value?

Tags: c++, casting, operators

For a class A, an integer conversion operator would look something like;

```
operator int() //Here we don't specify any return type
{
    return intValue;
}
```

How is the above function able to return a value when its return value type appears not to be specified? It doesn't appear to return "anything", but I know it's not `void`.

How is this meaningful when a return type is not specified?

Comment: I think elevating the importance of the type signature too much is the barrier in your thinking. The type signature is *usually* what tells you the return type -- *except* in the case of conversion functions, where the return type is given by what syntactically looks like the "name" of the function.

Answer (score 27):

The return type of `operator T()` is always `T`. It's a special case of C++.

It does not use standard function prototype syntax `T foo()` because 2 functions with the same name differing only by the return type cannot coexist (e.g. `int foo()` conflicts with `double foo()`). If this syntax is used then you can only define 1 conversion operator overload, which is undesirable.

Comment: For `operator const T()`, the return type is `T` or `const T`?

Answer (score 7):

The return value of `operator T()` where `T` is a type is always `T`.

Answer (score 4):

The name of the conversion operator is its type. If this were not the case, you could define an int conversion operator (for example) that actually returned a double. A somewhat similar line of thinking applies to constructors, which also do not have a return type.